# Zeppelin: Facing error after running scala query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

PooledByteBufAllocator.metric()Lio/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocatorMetric;

Zeppelin Version: zeppelin-0.8.0
[image]

Comment: Spark version: spark-2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

This is issue of the embedded spark mode of zeppelin. Specify SPARK_HOME explicitly could solve this issue.

Comment: Still have same issue Here is my  zeppelin-env.sh file setting
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark-2.3.2/           
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--driver-memory 512M --executor-memory 1G"

export ZEPPELIN_PORT=9005 # Add this line to zeppelin-env.sh
export MASTER=spark://NN1:7077
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0/
Error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.metric()Lio/netty/buffer/PooledByteBufAllocatorMetric;